# How to append rows in CSV export in laravel

Tags: laravel, export-to-csv, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel

```
Laravel : 5.8
PHP : 7.2 
maatwebsite/excel : 3.1
```

I am using `maatwebsite/excel` package to export my large data set in CSV file, however, I couldn't find the way to append the rows in CSV file in the latest version of the package. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = User::get()->toArray();

    $headerData[] = ['Id','First Name','Last Name','Address'];

    $customData = array_merge($headerData,$data);
    $fileName = strtotime("now");
    Excel::create($fileName, function($excel) use ($customData,$headerData) {
    $excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) use ($customData, $headerData) {
        $sheet->fromArray($customData, null, 'A1', false, false);
    });
})->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: @MiraThakkar - Excel::load($path . '/exported.xls', function($reader) 
{
    $reader->sheet(function($sheet) 
    {
        $sheet->appendRow($data);
    });
})->export('xls');

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to append rows in the last of excel file:

```
// Append multiple rows
$sheet->rows(array(
    array('test5', 'test6'),
    array('test7', 'test8')
));
```

Comment: yeah, but new version does not support load method on Excel Facade.

Comment: @MiraThakkar Are you talking about the `load()` method??